# How to change XML attribute on the client side and then save the result on the server side?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, jsp, xml-parsing

My Question is :

I read a xml file from server side and then present them into client side, next I want to edit the data, like : using setAttribute() method to change them. now here comes problem:
I dont want to only modified them on the client side, but on the server side also, and them save the xml file. how can I do that, using JSP and Javascript ? 
Here is some initial ideas, but some part is not working ... 
such as the line : " <%count%> = length; "

and i think it is really make the page load slowly if i write xml line by line...
is there a better to do this ?

thank you :)

```
<% String attribute[];
   int count;  %>
<script>
  //hide the part of reading xml file to xmlDoc
  var length = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").length;
  <%count%> = length; // this doesnt work ...???
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").item[i].setAttribute("score","1");
    <%attribute[i]%> =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").item[i].setAttribute("score");   
}
</script>
<%   String xmlString;
     String personNm ={"Bob","Mike","Lily"};
        for (int i;i < count;i++)
           xmlString = "<person score="+attribute[i]+">personNm[i]</person>";

      //here i use a out put buffer to print it line by line...
     outputFile = new File("result.xml");
     outputFile.createNewFile();
     FileWriter outfile = new FileWriter(outputFile);
     outfile.write(xmlString);
     outfile.close();  %>
```

Comment: You need to do an effort when asking a question if you want someone to be interested in!

Comment: @enguerran do an effort like what?... add more tags? or ?

Comment: Pay attention to the presentation. The English language and the code formatting.

Comment: as BalusC says: pay attention to the presentation.

Comment: Yes, Thanks , both you are right, I modified them again, hope it is more clear now, but I am not from english-spoken country... so I just do my best :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that JSP is executed on the server and Javascript will be executed on the client. On the server only the JSP is executed and the result is sent to the server. What your client will receive is the following :

```
<script>
//read xml file to xmlDoc

var length = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").length;
 = length;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").item[i].setAttribute("score","1");
    = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").item[i].setAttribute("score");
}
</script>
```

Notice that all the JSP tag where executed on the server and what the browser receive is the result. **No Javascript is executed on the server**.

What you probably want to do is to modify your XML on the server and after that return the result in the page.

Comment: so there is no way that I can transfer the value of client side to server side ?

Comment: @Camellia It is possible, simply not that way you are trying to do it. You have to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX) to communicate with the server.

Comment: thanks, but AJAX is big subject for me now, I dont have enough time to study it from beginning step by step, can you help me point out which kind of function can I use ?

Comment: @Camellia Ajax is rather trivial to use with jQuery. If you need example, you can take a look at the documentation of jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/